# $f^{-1}(D-C)=f^{-1}(D)-f^{-1}(C)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Please can you give me feedback on this proof?

> **Result:** Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a function. Let $C$, $D \subseteq B$. Then $f^{-1}(D-C)=f^{-1}(D)-f^{-1}(C)$.

> **Proof:** To show that $f^{-1}(D-C)=f^{-1}(D)-f^{-1}(C)$, it is sufficient to show that the set in each side is a subset of the other.
>
> Let $x \in f^{-1}(D-C)$. By definition, we see that $f(x) \in D-C$. Hence, $f(x) \in D$ and $f(x) \notin C$. We deduce that $x \in f^{-1}(D)$ and $x \notin f^{-1}(C)$. Then $x \in f^{-1}(D) - f^{-1}(C)$. Therefore $f^{-1}(D-C) \subseteq f^{-1}(D) - f^{-1}(C)$.
>
> Now, let $y \in f^{-1}(D) - f^{-1}(C)$. Then $y \in f^{-1}(D)$ and $y \notin f^{-1}(C)$. By definition, we see that $f(y) \in D$ and $f(y) \notin C$. From here we see that $f(y) \in D-C$. Then, by definition, $y \in f^{-1}(D-C)$. Therefore $f^{-1}(D)-f^{-1}(C) \subseteq f^{-1}(D-C)$.
>
> This ends the proof.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: The proof is good.

Comment: Sounds good. Well done!

Comment: At first I thought y'all meant Minkowski subtraction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) -- in which case this result is false. Now I see you mean setminus. Nice proof!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I was not sure I was using the definitions properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You can alternatively combine the two parts for a shorter proof as follows:

$$\begin{align*}x \in f^{-1}(D-C)&\iff f(x) \in D-C\\
&\iff f(x) \in D \text{ and } f(x) \notin C\\
&\iff x \in f^{-1}(D) \text{ and } x \notin f^{-1}(C)\\
&\iff x \in f^{-1}(D)-f^{-1}(C).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I thought that, but I was not sure if everything I was doing was an equivalence